# Lightroom Context Menu Export Does Not Run Plugins

Tags: lightroom, export

An odd behavior that tripped me a few times is that when exporting files using an Export Preset from the Context-Menu (Right-Click -> Export -> ) any export plugins specified for that preset are not run. Doing the export by choosing *Export...* from the main menu or context menu and selecting the same preset, runs the export plugin. This is annoying because if I forget than an export has a plugin, then I must export again and tell Lightroom to overwrite as there is no way to just run the plugin on the files which were just exported.

Is this expected? Most importantly, is there a workaround to get export plugins to be run every single time one does an export with the preset that specifies it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this expected?  IMO No. If you have defined a program in the 'Post Processing- After Export' dialog, and 'Added' that preset, it should work the same irrespective of which method you use to Export (Context or other).
I have LR CC2015.10.1 Windows-10. If I design an Export preset with Post Processing for Nik Silver Efex, it works for me from the R-Click context menu.
I consider the Post Processing program to always be a 'stand-alone' working executable program (not a plug-in) as is {Silver Efex Pro.exe}.